# Jupyterhub password for azure dsvm setup with ssh login

Tags: azure, azure-dsvm

I setup an azure dsvm using ssh keys instead of a username/password combo. Now, I am not sure how to log into the Jupyter hub because its asking for a username and password. What should the password be since I never entered one.

Answer (score 3):

JupyterHub does not support SSH keys, so you will need to set up a password on your local DSVM account to enable this login.

After ssh into the DSVM:

```
sudo passwd USERNAME NEWPASS
```

now try to login to jupyterhub with USERNAME NEWPASS as your credentials.

Alternatively, you might tunnel Jupyter over SSH: create a tunnel for, say, port 8080,  run "jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=8080" remotely, then access the notebooks at "http://localhost:8080".